# scanf(" %450[^\n]",str) not reading line by line

Tags: c

```
scanf("%d",&T);
printf("%d",T);
for(i=0;i<T;i++)
 {
    scanf("%450[^\n]",str2);
    printf("%s",str2);
 }
```

I am trying read the following using file redirection on the gcc compiler

```
3              // number of lines to read 
               // line 1 intentionally left blank(pressed enter)
hello world    // line 2 to read
hello world2   // line 3 to read
```

But iam getting the following output

```
3
                // blank
                // blank
                // blank
```

I have already read the previous posts on stack overflow on the usage of various varieties of scanf to read line by line.But none seems to work in my case.Where I went wrong?

Comment: 1) `scanf("%450[^\n]",str2);` never consumes a `'\n'`.  Although various `scanf()` work-arounds exist, recommend using `fgets()`.  2) Always check the return value from any input function like `scanf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read a line simply use fgets().

```
fgets(str2, length, stdin);
```

The complete example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int T, i;
    char str2[1024];
    fgets(str2, 1024, stdin);
    sscanf(str2, "%d", &T);
    printf("%d\n",T);
    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        fgets(str2, 1024, stdin);
        printf("%s", str2);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Of course if you can't rely on the input being valid you could also add some checks verifying the return value of fgets, and maybe use strtol instead of sscanf.

Comment: last line of the "hello world2" is not printing for the above given input.

Comment: The first scanf() doesn't consume the end of line after the number, and if you add "\n" in the format string it consumes that and the empty line too. I've added a full example using fgets() instead of scanf() that works.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
scanf("%450[^\n]",str2);
```

leaves the newline character in the input stream. Add a line to read a character and discard it.

```
for(i=0;i<T;i++)
{
    scanf("%450[^\n]",str2);
    fgetc(stdin);
    printf("%s\n",str2); // Add a newline to printf
}
```

**Update, in response to comment by OP**

There's newline character left on the input stream after `scanf("%d",&T);`. Add a line to read and discard that newline character too.

Updated function that works for me.

```
int main()
{
   int T;
   char str2[450] = {0};
   int i;

   scanf("%d",&T);

   // Discard everything after the number
   scanf("%*[^\n]"); // Discard all but the newline
   fgetc(stdin);     // Discard the newline

   printf("%d\n",T);
   for(i=0;i<T;i++)
   {
      scanf("%450[^\n]",str2);
      fgetc(stdin);
      printf("%s\n",str2);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and found that it successfully reads the first two lines "blank and hello world" as expected. "hello world2" is missing.

Comment: I saw the samething. Then I realized that there's newline character left on the input stream after `scanf("%d",&T);`. Add a line to read and discard that newline character too.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you need just to add a **newline** `\n` in the second `scanf`

```
scanf("\n%450[^\n]",str2); // note the \n before the % character
```

Morever, you need to add some **newlines** inside the function `printf` to get a *good* and *readable* output.

Comment: For the above specified input, iam getting helloworld,helloworld2,helloworld2. helloworld2 is printing twice. where as, iam interested to print as it is" blank,helloworld,helloworld2"

Comment: @helloworld: You have to test the result of `scanf()` and not try using the line if it doesn't report that it read one.

Comment: Note that the newline at the beginning of the format skips any white space (blanks, tabs, newlines) before starting to convert.